# How to change the height of webView dynamically?

Tags: ios, webview

I'm currently using webView to display news,below the news I intend to put some buttons.so I need to get the height of webView so as to change the position of buttons according to the height of webView after all are downloaded.in other words,how to change the height of webView dynamically?

Comment: self.webView.frame.size.height is what u want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
    {
        NSString *string = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"body\").offsetHeight;"];
        CGFloat height = [string floatValue] + 8;
        CGRect frame = [_webView frame];
        frame.size.height = height;
        [_webView setFrame:frame];

        if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(webViewController:webViewDidResize:)])
        {
            [[self delegate] webViewController:self webViewDidResize:frame.size];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Do this inside the delegate method webViewDidFinishLoad:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView
{
    CGFloat height = [[aWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.height"] floatValue];
    CGFloat width = [[aWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.width"] floatValue];
    aWebView.frame = CGRectMake(aWebView.frame.origin.x,aWebView.frame.origin.y,width, height);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The webView has method `sizeThatFits:` which returns the size of content once the webView is added in a view hierarchy and finished loading the html.

But this does not work without a caveat. You need to set the frame of webview to a low value before calling the fitting size method.

For eg: If you have a fixed width and variable height

```
//Set a very low height
CGRect webViewFrame = self.webView.frame;
webViewFrame.size.height = 5.0f;
self.webView.frame = webViewFrame;
//Re calculate the size that fits
CGSize size = [self.webView sizeThatFits:webViewFrame.size];
self.webViewFrame.size = size;
self.webView.frame = webViewFrame;
```

PS: I want to give credit to the original work. I'm still searching in SO

Answer (score 1):

```
According to your device type like iPhone 4 or iPhone 5 you can set your webview
The web view has finished loading.
    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

        [DejalActivityView removeView];

        if ([objSpineCustomProtocol windowHeight] == 480) {

            termsWebView.frame = CGRectMake(termsWebView.frame.origin.x
                                            ,termsWebView.frame.origin.y
                                            ,termsWebView.frame.size.width
                                            ,350);

        }

    }// End of Method webViewDidFinishLoad
```

//VKJ

Comment: This is not "dynamic",you just fix the height of webView to 350 while the device is iPhone 4.